# Hibernate: custom entity name

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Let's say I have an entity with a very long name:

```
@Entity
public class SupercalifragilisticexpialidociousPanda
{
    ...
}
```

Using Hibernate to persist it to a Postgres DB works flawlessly. Oracle, however, doesn't allow for table/column/index names longer than 30 characters. 
That should be easy to fix, since i can just specify the table name manually, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SuperPanda")
public class SupercalifragilisticexpialidociousPanda
{
    ...
}
```

Now everything is back to working perfectly... except that any references I have to the entity in other tables still use the long class name ("SupercalifragilisticexpialidociousPanda") instead of the short table name ("SuperPanda").

For instance, if the entity has an embedded ElementCollection, like this:

```
@ElementCollection
private Set<String> nicknames;
```

Hibernate will try to create a DB like this: `create table SupercalifragilisticexpialidociousPanda_nicknames`, which will naturally cause an `ORA-00972: identifier is too long` error.

The same thing also happens for `@OneToOne` associations, where the lookup column would be called something like `supercalifragilisticexpialidociousPanda_uuid`, which also fails with oracle.

Now, one option would be to add a `@CollectionTable(name="SuperPanda_nicknames")` and `@Column(name="...")` annotation manually to every field that references this entity, but that's a lot of work and really error-prone.

Is there a way to just tell Hibernate **once** to use the short name everywhere a reference to the entity is required?

I also tried setting the entity name, like this:

```
@Entity(name="SuperPanda")
@Table(name="SuperPanda")
public class SupercalifragilisticexpialidociousPanda
{
    ...
}
```

... but it doesn't fix the issue.

What does one normally do in such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually people give names for each database thing (table, column, index) by themselves. Letting Hibernate decide for you can lead to problem in future when you decide to refactor something.

All reference can be configured one way or another to use names you decide to use.

Ask specific question in case you can figure out the way to do it yourself.

Comment: Ok, thank you - I guess I'll have to get into the habit of manually naming everything :)